# Invalid Element Type upon import of custom React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to render a custom nav bar in my React application and I get an Invalid Type error.

I'm aware that there are default and named imports/exports in React, however I am exporting the CustomNavBar class as default and importing it as default in App.jsx. Other posters have mentioned that it might be an issue with package versions but I don't know where to start fixing that.

App.jsx:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Resume from './components/Resume';
import CustomNavBar from './components/CustomNavBar';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <CustomNavBar />
          <Route exact path = "/" component={Home} />
          <Route path = "/about" component={About} />
          <Route path = "/resume" component={Resume} />
        </div>
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Code runs as normal when the CustomNavBar component is omitted.

CustomNavBar.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'  
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


export default class CustomNavBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} to="/">
                            Home
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey={2} componentClass={Link} to="/about">
                            About
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey={3} componentClass={Link} to="/resume">
                            Resume
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my_site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.8",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The error:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `CustomNavBar`.

/****SOLVED****/
Header is no longer exported from bootstrap, brand and toggle should not be contained in a div in bootstrap 4.

Comment: Your custom nav bar component could just be a plain functional component like your app component. As for your error, I can't see anything wrong, I would start taking things out of the navbar like navebar.header and just keep deleting stuff and see if it works. Only thing I can think is the default prop on navbar.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the docs of react-bootstrap, I don't think it exposes a `Navbar.Header`. Could that be the problem?
I have the same hunch for `NavItem`. It seems to me that it should say `Nav.Item`.

Comment: This is correct. Per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558387/bootstrap-4-navbar-header-usage

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `Navbar.Header` [was removed in `v1`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/migrating/#navbar):

> Navbar removed Navbar.Header removed Navbar.Form removed fluid, use
>   your own Container component in. inverse removed and replaced with
>   variant="dark" positioning props have been consolidated into
>   fixed={top|bottom} and sticky={top|bottom}, staticTop has been removed

Comment: Concise and links provided 